# Python script to get iam user list who has not used Access keys more than 10 day

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have prepared the python script which will get the iam user list who has not used their access key for more than 10 days.

But I'm getting below error:

> AttributeError: 'iam.User' object has no attribute 'accesskey_last_used'

```
import json
import boto3
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

resource = boto3.resource('iam')
client = boto3.client('iam')

today = datetime.datetime.now()
final_report = ''
final_result = ''

number = int(1)

for user in resource.users.all():
   if user.accesskey_last_used is not None:
       delta = (today - user.access_key_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
   if delta >= 10:
       final_result= str(number) + " username: " + [user.user_name][0] + " - " + str(delta) + "days\n"
       final_report = final_report + final_result
       number = number + 1

print("final_report")
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite accurate. There is no `accesskey_last_used` attribute on an `iam.User` object.

Also, a user can have multiple Access Keys and each of these Access Keys can have an `AccessKeyLastUsed` property.

Therefore, you will need to use `client` calls instead of `resource` calls and loop through each Access Key for each User:

```
import boto3
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

resource = boto3.resource('iam')
client = boto3.client('iam')

today = datetime.datetime.now()
final_report = ''
number = 1

# For every user
for user in resource.users.all():

    # Get Access Keys for the User
    keys_response = client.list_access_keys(UserName=user.user_name)
    last_access = None

    # For every Access Key associate with the user
    for key in keys_response['AccessKeyMetadata']:

        last_used_response = client.get_access_key_last_used(AccessKeyId=key['AccessKeyId'])
        if 'LastUsedDate' in last_used_response['AccessKeyLastUsed']:
            accesskey_last_used = last_used_response['AccessKeyLastUsed']['LastUsedDate']
            if last_access is None or accesskey_last_used < last_access:
                last_access = accesskey_last_used

    # More than x days since last access?
    if last_access is not None:
        delta = (today - last_access.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
        if delta >= 10:
            final_report += str(number) + " username: " + [user.user_name][0] + " - " + str(delta) + " days\n"
            number += 1

print(final_report)
```